# Why does MSVC find ineligible get() in structured binding?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, structured-bindings

Consider the following code:

```c++
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
struct A
{
    void get() {}    // #1
};

template <typename ...Ts>
struct B : A<Ts>... {};

template <typename ...Ts>
struct std::tuple_size<B<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2> {};

template <std::size_t I, typename ...Ts>
struct std::tuple_element<I, B<Ts...>>
{
    using type = int;
};

template <std::size_t I, typename ...Ts>
constexpr int get(B<Ts...>)    // #2
{
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    B<double, long long> b;
    auto [x, y] = b;
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
}
```

GCC accepts the above code and outputs `2, 2` as I excepted ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vvWb9ej4h)), but MSVC complains ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fhT9ah3bj)).

> error C2385: ambiguous access of 'get'

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

> For each identifier, a variable whose type is "reference to
> `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`" is introduced: lvalue reference if its
> corresponding initializer is an lvalue, rvalue reference otherwise.
>
> The initializer for the i-th variable is
>
> - `e.get<i>()`, if lookup for the identifier get in the scope of ***E*** by
>   class member access lookup finds at least one declaration that is a
>   function template whose first template parameter is a non-type
>   parameter
> - Otherwise, `get<i>(e)`, where `get` is looked up by
>   argument-dependent lookup only, ignoring non-ADL lookup.

From my understanding, the member `get()` (line #1) does not meet the quoted requirements (it's even not a template), and the compiler should choose the non-member `get()` (line #2). GCC works as I excepted, but MSVC seems stuck at the member `get()`, ignoring whether it is eligible.

Which compiler is correct? Why does MSVC find ineligible `get()` in structured binding?

Comment: clang also fails: https://godbolt.org/z/Mvz45ojxM

Comment: It says that member lookup for `get` is performed, but that lookup is ambiguous (since there are two base classes with a `get` member) and therefore makes the program ill-formed. I don't see anything saying that the lookup failure is ignored.

Comment: @user17732522 so gcc is wrong and msvc/clang are correct?

Comment: @方圆圆 Yes, assuming I am correct. I have not spent much time looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[dcl.struct.bind]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#4.sentence-3):

> If a search for the name `get` in the scope of `E` finds at least one declaration that is a function template whose first template parameter is a non-type parameter, the initializer is `e.get<i>()`.

(`E` is the type of the backing variable, in this case `B<double, long long>`.)

If the search results in an ambiguity between members of different bases, we hit [[class.member.lookup]/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#6.sentence-2), making the program ill-formed (regardless of whether the declarations found are of function templates).

---

[CWG2567](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2567.html) is closely related: it deals with a similar scenario in the context of lookup for overloaded operators.

Under the proposed resolution for that issue, this program becomes well-formed: the search for `get` in `B<double, long long>` would fail gracefully (yielding nothing), allowing a non-member `get` to be used as a fallback.